# Convert Prototype Ajax Responders to jQuery

Tags: jquery, prototypejs

I am looking for help to convert this prototype to jquery. Thank you.

```
Ajax.Responders.register({ 
  onCreate: function(){
    if($('ajax_busy') && Ajax.activeRequestCount > 0){ 
   Effect.Appear('ajax_busy', {duration: 0.5, queue: 'end'});
    } 
  },
  onComplete: function(){ 
 if($('ajax_busy') && Ajax.activeRequestCount == 0){
      Effect.Fade('ajax_busy', {duration: 0.5, queue: 'end'});
    } 
  }  
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think ajaxStart ajaxStop

http://api.jquery.com/ajaxSend/

http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStop/